# How make use of liquibase-modify-column.jar in maven project?

Tags: java, xml, maven, migration, liquibase

```html
<databaseChangeLog 
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
  xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd 
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="Administrator" id="20" runOnChange="true"> 
        <modifyColumn tableName="TEST_TABLE">
            <column name="FIELD_NAME" type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(250)" />
        </modifyColumn>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**I'm new to liquibase, Can anybody help me on how to use liquibase-modify-column jar for using modifyColumn feature in liquibase 3.6.3 to fix the current problem.**

**cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifyColumn}'**. One of '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":comment, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createView, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":renameView, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropView, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":insert, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addColumn, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":sql, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createProcedure, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropProcedure, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":sqlFile, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":renameTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":renameColumn, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropColumn, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":mergeColumns, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifyDataType, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createSequence, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":alterSequence, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropSequence, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":createIndex, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropIndex, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addNotNullConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropNotNullConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addForeignKeyConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropForeignKeyConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropAllForeignKeyConstraints, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addPrimaryKey, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropPrimaryKey, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addLookupTable, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addAutoIncrement, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addDefaultValue, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropDefaultValue, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":addUniqueConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":dropUniqueConstraint, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":customChange, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":update, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":delete, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":loadData, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":loadUpdateData, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":executeCommand, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":empty, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":stop, "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":rollback, WC[##other:"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"], "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifySql}' is expected.

versions used: liquibase-3.6.3 and liquibase-modify-column-3.1.jar

Comment: I don't know these packages, but the error you're getting stems from a malformed XML.The tag ```<modifyColumn>``` needs a child that was not provided as by the file's schema definition. If you could provide the XML that's giving this error we could look into it.

Comment: @MaxRumford i have updated with xml data. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

**POM.xml**

```html
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-modify-column</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

```html
<databaseChangeLog 
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
  xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd 
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="Administrator" id="20" runOnChange="true"> 
        <ext:modifyColumn tableName="TEST_TABLE">
            <column name="FIELD_NAME" type="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR(250)" />
        </ext:modifyColumn>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

adding liquibase-modify-column.jar in liqubase dependency and using
ext:modifyColumn </ext:modifyColumn>
will make to use modifyColumn functional with latest liquibase

https://forum.liquibase.org/t/custom-preconditions-as-an-extension-not-working/1428

Comment: As I understand the linked forum post, the ```*-ext.xsd``` schema is a blank check xsd allowing **everything**. You thus give up type safety usually provided by using xsd. To keep safe with XMLs you should, if possible, update to use the current structure using the ```<modifyDataType>```. Thanks for posting an answer!

Comment: yes, what you said was correct @MaxRumford. Changing my current changelogfile will make lot more works. so i'm going with -ext.

Answer (score 0):

`<modifyColumn>` is not allowed where you placed it. As far as I can see in the docs `<modifyColumn>` is no valid data type at all for liquibase. Instead you'll have to put any of the tags the error message mentions. You should check https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/home.html for a list of valid Change Types that can be used under `<changeSet>`. Based on what you put into your `<modifyColumn>` tag I guess you're looking for the [modifyDataType](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/modify-data-type.html).

Comment: You are right @MaxRumford, But we can also use modify-column.jar to make use of modiFyColumn tag as per this liquibase github wiki - https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-modify-column/wiki

Comment: Your XML is regerencing ```http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd``` as schema to be used which does not contain the ```modifyColumn``` type. When manually changing the target namespace and schema source from ```http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.0.xsd``` to ```http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.0 http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.0.xsd``` the xml validates correctly. You might want to check if you correctly invoke the liquibase-modify-column-3.1 methods.

Comment: hey thanks for your great support @MaxRumford. I can able to use with same schema by adding ext before modifyColumn as follows <ext:modifyColumn>. This made my migration to work fine.

Comment: Just for clarification (and to be consulted when others find this post): Can you post an answer on how you managed to do this? Please provide the steps on how you made your program work the way you wanted it to, e.g. new code statements, manual modification of properties etc... No problem, happy to help! :)